# Add ModelState.AddModelError without reload the page (mvc4)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 and I have 2 methods in my controller:

**Get Method**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new User
    {
        Client= new Catastro_Cliente()
        Genre = ClienteRepository.GetGenres(),
        Type= ClienteRepository.GetTypes()
    };

    ViewBag.Genre = new SelectList(vm.Genre, "IdGenre", "Genre");
    ViewBag.Type= new SelectList(vm.Type, "IdType", "Type");
    return View(vm);
}
```

**Post Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CrearUsuario(Catastro_Cliente client)
{
    if(Validator(client.document))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("NoDocument", "The document is invalid or not registered");
    }

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying keep all the data that the user filled in before the post Method,

I tried with `return RedirectToAction("Create");` but it always refreshes the page.

Comment: you mean you want to put something like `RedirectToAction` inside `if(Validator(client.document)){...}`?

Comment: @Rhumborl yes, but I need not reload the page to keep the client infomration on the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass back the posted model when you call `View`. What you need is something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CrearUsuario(Catastro_Cliente client)
{
    if(Validator(client.document))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("NoDocument", "The document is invalid or not registered");
    }

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save to database of whatever
        // this is a successful response
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // There's some error so return view with posted data:
    return View(client);
}
```